# Clarification on Stores in Reactjs-Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am currently learning how to use Redux in my ReactJS application and all the tutorials I've seen lead me to believe that there can only be one store in Redux.  In a real-world applications, you may have multiple streams of data coming from a REST api or some other source.  So, for example, I may be looking at a list of customers in one component and a list of projects in another and list of users in yet another.  My question is: Does Redux allow you to create a store for each entity with it's own reducer and actions?  For example, a customer store, a project store and user store?  If not how would one organize this in a single store without everything getting convoluted?  Thanks.

*** EDIT ***
So my state would look something like:

```
let initalState={
     customers:{
          data:[]
          ...
     },
     projects:{
          data:[]
          ...
     }
     users:{
          data:[]
          ...
     }
}
```

Comment: You could have multiple stores in your application but I don't think it's a common usecase. To resolve your problem you can combine multiple reducers with combineReucers https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers/

Comment: But all the data from say customers, projects, users, etc live inside a single state?

Comment: they live in the same store but the data will be managed by multiples reducers (on reducer for customers, another for projects, another for users...)

Comment: Edited my post to visualize what the state would look like.  Is this along the lines of how this would be done?

Answer (score 1):

I think that [combinereducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers/) is what you are looking for.

> As your app grows more complex, you'll want to split your reducing function into separate functions, each managing independent parts of the state.
>
> The combineReducers helper function turns an object whose values are different reducing functions into a single reducing function you can pass to createStore.

Imagine you want to manage the customers, projects and users.

You will get one reducer per feature :

```
const customersInitialState = {data:[], ...}
export default function customersReducer(state = customersInitialState , action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD':
      return {...state, data: [...state.data, action.payload]}
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Then you will combine all theses reducers into a single one

```
export default combineReducers({
  customers: customersReducer,
  projects: projectsReducer,
  users: usersReducer
})

const store = createStore(reducer)
```

Finally the state of your store will be like this :

```
{
  customers: {data: [], ...},
  projects: {data: [], ...},
  users: {data: [], ...},
}
```

Comment: I'm more interested in where the data is stored from a datasource such as a REST api.  Is the data stored in a single state?

Comment: I edited my answer to give you more information about combining multiple reducers